# Python Selenium with Proxy

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script that opens a browser with a proxy that looks like this:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import os
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "64.235.204.107:8080"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=' + PROXY)
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-erros')

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/")
```

Im using http proxies but so far none have worked, they all result in the not connected page. Is this because all the proxies are just really slow or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Where are you getting these proxies from? Do they work whne you manually configure with them?

Comment: Im getting them from openproxy.space

Comment: `Pinging 64.235.204.107 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.`

the server is down and your question is a little bit unsalvageable, I am flagging it to be closed